# Updating ExpandableListView in OnActivityResult

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

In my fragment I have an ExpandableListView, which has Categories as groups and Base_Items as children, they're coming from a DB. From here I open an Intent for result to enter new Items. OnActivityResult I want the new item to appear immediately in the ExpandableListView and then enter it to the DB. I tried that:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        switch(requestCode)
        {
        case Constants.Request_Codes.REQUEST_CODE_CREATE_NEW_ITEM:
            String new_item_name = data.getExtras().getString("ITEM_NAME");
            int new_item_category = data.getExtras().getInt("ITEM_CATEGORY");

            Base_Item bi = new Base_Item(-1, new_item_category, new_item_name);
            ArrayList<Base_Item> arr_bi = arr_all_categories.get(new_item_category).getCategory_items();
            arr_bi.add(bi);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            manager.add_new_base_item(bi);
            break;
        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

The new item is being inserted into DB just fine, but the ListView doesn't update. I have to exit the app and reopen it to see the new item in the list.

How can I update the ExpandableListView and see the new item immediately? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I ended up just repopulating the ListView again in my `onActivityResult` method. I'm not sure it's the best way (speaking of performance) and perhaps I should've been keep looking for the answer, but for now it just works.